# Android Navigation Bar and Status Bar transparency with insets

Tags: android, kotlin, android-layout, material-design

I followed [this guide](https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/edge-to-edge) when trying to implement a transparent navigation and status bar (edge-to-edge) for Android. I'm using a custom top bar so that I can hide it on scroll.

```
    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        app:liftOnScroll="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
            android:id="@+id/topAppBar"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap"
            app:title="Calorie Vault"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Toolbar.Primary"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize" />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
```

I added `WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)` to my MainActivity.
Then, in my Fragment, I used insets to push up the UI so that 3-button-navigation wouldn't cover some of the tappable interfaces.

```
        ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(view) { view, windowInsets ->
            val insets = windowInsets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars())

            view.updatePadding(
                top = insets.top, // this is for the tool bar inset
                bottom = insets.bottom // lift up the bottom part of the UI above navigation bar
            )
            WindowInsetsCompat.CONSUMED
        }
```

My theme looks like this:

```
    <style name="Theme.Calorie_vault" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Primary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/white</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/light_teal</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/black</item>
        <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/light_teal</item>
        <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/light_teal</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
        <!-- Status bar color. -->
        <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:enforceStatusBarContrast">false</item>
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="android:enforceNavigationBarContrast">false</item>
        <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">true</item>
    </style>
```

But those insets that I added aren't transparent. Here's a picture of what they look like: [screen shot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KjeZl.png) Notice the gesture navigation bar is colored differently.

How do I get rid of the color of the insets?

Answer (score 0):

Set your view's background to transparent.